# How do time periods in Facebook insights work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the example I am pasting below, I first request insights data daily for the last month. The second one is weekly, and the third is per 28 days (let's call it monthly). My problem is that the data for days_28 is exactly the same as day, whereas it should at least be like the weekly data (I.E. the data for the last 28 days should at least be 61, not just 1).

Why does this happen? Am I interpreting the data wrong?

The URLs are below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/day?since=-1month
https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/week?since=-1month
https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/days_28?since=-1month
```

Here is the daily data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/day", 
      "name": "page_stories", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-19T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-20T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-21T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-28T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-30T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-01T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-03T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-04T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-05T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-06T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-07T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-08T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-09T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-10T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-11T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-12T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-13T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-14T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-15T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-16T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Daily Page Stories", 
      "description": "Daily The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/day?since=1371647555&until=1374153155", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/day?since=1376658755&until=1379164355"
  }
}
```

Here is the weekly data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/week", 
      "name": "page_stories", 
      "period": "week", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-19T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-20T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-21T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-28T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-30T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-01T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-03T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-04T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-05T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-06T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-07T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-08T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-09T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-10T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-11T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 2, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-12T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 29, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-13T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 50, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-14T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 61, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-15T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 61, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-16T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Weekly Page Stories", 
      "description": "Weekly The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/week?since=1371647903&until=1374153503", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/week?since=1376659103&until=1379164703"
  }
}
```

And here is the monthly data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/days_28", 
      "name": "page_stories", 
      "period": "days_28", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-19T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-20T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-21T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-27T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-28T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-29T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-30T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-07-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-01T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-03T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-04T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-05T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-06T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-07T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-08T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-09T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-10T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-11T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-12T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-13T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-14T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 0, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-15T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 1, 
          "end_time": "2013-08-16T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "28 Days Page Stories", 
      "description": "28 Days The number of stories created about your Page. (Total Count)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/days_28?since=1371647956&until=1374153556", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1404223219793416/insights/page_stories/days_28?since=1376659156&until=1379164756"
  }
}
```